# Affect spacing of procedurally generated rings?

Tags: procedural

I am looking to procedurally generate a texture of rings that will get closer to each other the further from the origin point they move, the effect can be reasonably recreated with mesh but i was looking to use a texture of some sort, end goal of being to generate stylized eyes as seen below

[image: intended effect]

[image: Concentric rings generated with an array]

[image: Desired effect with mesh]

Desired effect with mesh

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:
[image]

You're going to need a Wave Texture for sure

Comment: This is good but not quite i am going for, aim was for a central point being able to move anywhere and having concentric rings partially follow that center ring, like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdxs5.gif . This is made with mesh and a array midifier